# iOS - Fail to update table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

My table is not uptading during insertion. Also not showing in tableview but after click add "New record" message comes with "Record is added" so there is no any errors

Insertion in a table function:

```
-(int) insert:(NSString *)filePath withBrand:(NSString *)brand
{
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
    }
    else
    {
        NSString * query  = [NSString
                             stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO brands (bikeBrandName) VALUES (?)"];
        char * errMsg;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String] ,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
        if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to insert record  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Also tried this one:

```
-(int) insert:(NSString *)filePath withBrand:(NSString *)brand
{
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
    }
    else
    {
        NSString * query  = [NSString
                                 stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO brands (bikeBrandName) VALUES (\"%@\")",brand];
        char * errMsg;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String] ,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
        if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to insert record  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't

```
INSERT INTO brands (bikeBrandName) VALUES (\"%@\")",brand
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO brands (bikeBrandName) VALUES ('%@')",brand
                                           ^  ^
```

---

To debug further, use check [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

*For sure it will help*

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but is not working still not updating

Comment: still is not working....tried the tutorial but is difficult to implement to my code because using other way to insert into db